# Android App freezing after setting image bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, freeze

I am working on an app that has a background image. Because this image is really large I've used some code to make sure that is is small enough to not let the app run out of memory. But after setting the bitmap to the ImageView the app freezes and starts skipping frames. When I press on a button, nothing happens, no animation and no execution of any method. Here is my code:

```
package com.github.legosteen11.testing;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView mImg;
        mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        mImg.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_1, width, height));
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.github.legosteen11.testing.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Welcome!"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="How long will you be away?"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amountDays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daysTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/amountDays"
                android:text="days"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/amountDays"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continueDaysButton"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="helloWorld"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

edit:
logcat, there are no errors but thanks for the comments here it is :)

```
05-04 14:58:32.354 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.github.legosteen11.testing-2/lib/arm64
05-04 14:58:32.401 18034-18046/com.github.legosteen11.testing W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.270ms
05-04 14:58:32.403 18034-18046/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1969(115KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 19MB/19MB, paused 23.077ms total 41.996ms
05-04 14:58:32.643 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.github.legosteen11.testing-2/lib/arm64
05-04 14:58:32.758 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-04 14:58:33.695 18034-18095/com.github.legosteen11.testing D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-04 14:58:33.748 18034-18095/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 63c06b2, I8366cd0437
                                                                        Build Date                       : 12/06/15
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                                                                        Local Branch                     : mybranch17112971
                                                                        Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.9_v2
                                                                        Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-04 14:58:33.753 18034-18095/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-04 14:58:35.205 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 14:58:36.561 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 14:58:37.956 18034-18034/com.github.legosteen11.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Add logcat for get best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your code on different thread 
It will load on different thread so your ui will not have any load.
Declare this outside of onCreate as Global

```
ImageView mImg;

    public class DownloadFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            Context mContext;

            public DownloadFromServer(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                 mImg.setBitmap(s);             
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected ScData doInBackground(String... params) {
              Bitmap bmp=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_1, width, height);
                return bmp;
            }
        }
```